# How to display childrens custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, filters, child-pages, post-meta

I need help, I have a page that I want to display content from the page children, I get the content but not the custom fields!

I've tried this but it dosnt work, what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc&parent='.$post->ID);
    foreach($pages as $page) {
?>

<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); ?>

<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($page->post_content, 'custom_tagline')); ?>


<?php } ?>
```

Please HELP!

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($page->post_content, 'custom_tagline')); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($page->ID, 'custom_tagline')); ?>
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta